# File sync service over internet with users and rights

Tags: file-synchronization

I am looking for a file sync system with multiple user accounts and customizable rights on folders or files, and a Windows client software (can be command-line).

A system like Hubic or Dropbox is fine, but it does not allow multiple users and rights.

Paying is ok, as well as building a system upon our own Linux server.

I tried Webdav, but it does not allow file moving and you can't access files when offline.
I tried sftp, but it's damn slow and you can't access files when offline.

Googled a lot, but couldn't find a perfect solution.. Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe *Git Annex* – take a look at [relevant posts at our site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=git+annex) (just 8 posts, so it shouldn't take too long ;)